# Mysterious rep increase by 100 points

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, reputation

On [Role Playing Games Stack Exchange](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/), after being off for about two weeks, I noticed, to my great surprise, that I have 201 rep.  I had 101 previously (+100 for associated the account). Where did those +100 come from?  Not from any questions or answers (I have neither on that site).  And to prove the point, my rep graph is completely barren.

I suspect it's just a fluke that will go away at some point.

EDIT: /reputation says:

```
total votes: 0
-- bonuses   (200)
-- 2010-12-09 rep 0     = 201       

** rep this week (3/6/2011 - 3/12/2011): 0
** rep this month (3/1/2011 - 3/31/2011): 0
** rep this quarter (1/1/2011 - 3/31/2011): 0
** rep this year (1/1/2011 - 12/31/2011): 0
** total rep 201 :)

days represented 0
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days
rep cap was exceeded on 0 days
```

Comment: What does http://rpg.stackexchange.com/reputation output?

Comment: So, 200 bonuses.  But from what?

Comment: @jae As far as I know the only thing that currently gives you a bonus is the 100 for account association; it looks like you somehow got that  bonus twice, which is a bug

Comment: You could always trigger a recalc and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Michael that's what I thought to, so I suspected it's a bug  @Brandon: I was playing with the thought.  Guess I'll go ahead and do it.

Comment: Clicked the rep recalc button... it isn't instantaneous, is that vague memory correct?  Because if it is, it didn't change, still +200 from bonus(es).

Comment: @jae It should be pretty much instantaneous

Comment: Complaining about too much reputation?  Never thought I'd see that. lol

Comment: Well, it would seem that the DB decided you're special and gave you an extra 100 rep.  Congratulations.

Comment: we have isolated the bug and are working on a fix

Comment: Wow, the rep fairy **is** real and @waffles is killing it!

Comment: @Tim lol  @waff: will the bug be named after me?

Comment: Seems it's fixed, at least the mysterious increase has disappeared again.  *phew*... wait, I'm not glad to have lost rep, or am I? ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah I remember this, it was a concurrency bug where a handful of people got "double" the association bonus.

We fixed the bug :)

Comment: "We, uh, we fixed the *glitch*. So they won't have a double association bonus anymore, so it'll just work itself out naturally."