# Instant 100 rep boost without doing anything?

Tags: support, reputation, association-bonus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Association +100's not showing in rep graph?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74621/association-100s-not-showing-in-rep-graph)

Just earlier today, my rep on Stack Overflow was 878. I came back just now, to realize that my reputation has automagically boosted by 100. I went to the reputation tab on my page, and noticed that I had not recieved any reputation. Here are the before and after (thank goodness I left an old tab open in the browser):

[image]

This looks very similar to [Mysterious rep increase by 100 points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82227/mysterious-rep-increase-by-100-points), but apparently that bug was fixed.

What exactly happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SO blog; [Cross-Site Account Associations](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/):

> There is a +100 reputation bonus for every association you make, if either the source or target account in the association has at least 200 reputation.
>
> An account can have a 100 point bonus awarded for being in the same “network” of associated accounts if any of the associated accounts has 200 rep or more. This bonus is only awarded once per account — so if you associate four accounts, you’ll get +100 reputation on each site.
>
> This is intended to give established users a “leg up” when we start new sites, so they can have an account with 101 rep instead of the default 1.

---

Basically you got a 100 rep bonus on SO for creating an account here on Meta Stack Overflow.

If you open your [`/reputation` audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), you should see something like this at the very top:

```
total votes: XXXX
-- bonuses   (100)  <- yay, bonus!
```

Comment: If I got 200 rep on some of the Stack Exchange sites and my other accounts got the 100 rep bonus.
When I, after this point, create a new account on a new site, associated with my account, will it receive 1 or 101 rep by default?

Comment: @Steven 101. You always get the assoc bonus no matter when you create the account.